# How to implements a custom view within some fragments?

Tags: android

I want to implement a custom view within some Fragments, and this view doesn't have any dependency on activity, this way I can share it as a common UI component to others.

But I have a problem when trying to use FragmentManager to manage those Fragments inside the custom view, how can I get a FragmentManager instance? Generally, we can get it from Activity, but in my case, what should I do would be more reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

If your custom view is inflated by a fragment you have access to `getParentFragmentManager` there is more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

> But I have a problem when trying to use FragmentManager to manage those Fragments inside the custom view, how can I get a FragmentManager instance? Generally, we can get it from Activity, but in my case, what should I do would be more reasonable?

The best way to do it is to define an interface in the view to describe what events it has, then the fragment that hosts this view will implement this interface and actually handle it.

```
fun View.onClick(clickListener: (View) -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener(clickListener)
}



class MyView: FrameLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    interface Listener {
        fun onSomeEvent(someData: SomeData)
    }

    var listener: Listener? = null

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        val binding = MyViewBinding.bind(this)
        with(binding) {
            someButton.onClick {
                listener?.onSomeEvent(someData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment), MyView.Listener {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = MyFragmentBinding.bind(view)
        with(binding) {
            myView.listener = this@MyFragment
        }
    }
}
```